# Type-safer way to implement event driven architecture?

Tags: java, events, generics, types

I'm trying to implement a extendable even driven architecture in Java. Unfortunately I can't make it totally type safe. The following is what I did.

First I define the event. It's an almost empty class to be extended.

```
public abstract class Event {
    public final Class<? extends Event> getEventType() {
        return this.getClass();
    }
}
```

And the listener:

```
public interface Listener<T extends Event> {
    Class<T> getEventType();
    void onEvent(T event);
}
```

So far so good. But when I tried to implement the event dispatcher, I got stuck.

```
public class EventDispatcher {
    private Map<Class<? extends Event>, Collection<Listener>> listenersDict = new HashMap<>();

    public void registerListener(Listener listener) {
        Class<? extends Event> eventType = listener.getEventType();
        Collection<Listener> listeners = listenersDict.get(eventType);

        if(listeners == null) {
            listeners = new ArrayList<>();
            listenersDict.put(eventType, listeners);
        }
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void dispatch(Event event) {
        Class<? extend Event> eventType = event.getEventType();
        Collection<Listener> listeners = listenersDict.get(eventType);

        if(listeners != null) {
            for(Listener listener : listeners) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // Necessary Evil?
                listener.onEvent(event);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you saw I have to use `@SuppressWarnings`. I tried every way I can figure out, but one of `registerListener` and `dispatch` always be type-unsafe. (Changing `Listener` to `Listener<Event>` or `Listener<? extends Event>` in `EventDispatcher` doesn't work. I really tried.)

Is it possible to implement an architecture with the same flexibility(extendable event and listener, a single dispatcher handling different listeners), but without unsafe code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I suggest that you don't use the class for comparison, and instead use an `EventType` enum and use that instead, but that is fairly easy to replace.

Secondly, please excuse my use of java 1.6 (notice the replacements of `<>` syntax).

As for the issue, you weren't using the `getEventType()` method on the `Listener` interface. Also you don't need to take in an object of type `T` in the `onEvent()` method.

Most of the change was made to EventDispatcher:

```
public class EventDispatcher {
    private Map<Class<? extends Event>, Collection<Listener<? extends Event>>> listenersDict = new HashMap<Class<? extends Event>, Collection<Listener<? extends Event>>>();

    public void registerListener(Listener<? extends Event> listener) {
        Class<? extends Event> eventType = listener.getEventType();
        Collection<Listener<? extends Event>> listeners = listenersDict.get(eventType);

        if(listeners == null) {
            listeners = new ArrayList<Listener<? extends Event>>();
            listenersDict.put(eventType, listeners);
        }
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void dispatch(Event event) {
        Class<? extends Event> eventType = event.getEventType();
        Collection<Listener<? extends Event>> listeners = listenersDict.get(eventType);

        if(listeners != null) {
            for(Listener<? extends Event> listener : listeners) {
                if (listener.getEventType() == eventType) {
                    listener.onEvent(event);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Listener interface has slightly changed

```
public interface Listener<T extends Event> {
    Class<T> getEventType();

    void onEvent(Event event);
}
```

There was no change to the Event class:

```
public abstract class Event {
    public final Class<? extends Event> getEventType() {
        return this.getClass();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

In response to @jonathan.cone, I would like to point out that this *solution* does suffer from losing information in classes that implement the Listener interface which may be a deal breaker.

Comment: This solution is mostly right, but removing the parameterized method parameter from onEvent makes generics pointless for the whole thing.

Comment: @jonathan.cone - hmm, dilemma. I'm not sure that there is a type-safe way of doing this due to type-erasure

Comment: After some days of research, now I believe the best way is not to use generic in this case. So I pick this one as best answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you declared some generic type-parameters on methods *inside* dispatch(), you could have Java binding the Event subtype to those methods & selecting an appropriate type.

As it is,

```
Class<? extend Event> eventType = event.getEventType();
```

doesn't bind the Event subtype to any named type-parameter;  so the information goes nowhere & can't be further used by the compiler.

For example:

```
public <ET extends Event>  void dispatch (ET event) {
    Collection<Listener<ET>> listeners = getListeners( event);
    if(listeners != null) {
        for (Listener<ET> listener : listeners) {
            listener.onEvent( event);
        }
    }
}

private <ET extends Event>  Collection<Listener<ET>> getListeners (ET event) {
    Class<ET> eventType = event.getEventType();   // might work, if you genericized Event on itself..
    Collection<Listener<ET>> listeners = (Collection<Listener<ET>>)(Collection) listenersDict.get( eventType);  // will always needs cast.
}
```

However, you'll probably find -- at a certain point -- that can't be completely "type verified" by the compiler. Don't worry about it.

---

You'll also find that "exactly matching" a Class isn't ideal -- since *subtype events* should theoretically be received by any listener registering to receive the supertype.

Matching with inheritance can be checked using `Class.isAssignableFrom()`, and you can even cache the results into a map so you know what listener categories should be fired, but -- as someone else said -- it's simpler & far more efficient to use an Enum or int-field as your type-system.

Comment: `Class<ET> eventType = event.getEventType();` this line can't even be compiled.